# Disable an mqtt inject node using an UI switch NODE RED

Tags: mqtt, node-red

Sorry for my english and my maybe bad question but i'm  new to this.
For a project I'm trying to disable a mqtt inject by using a switch in my node-red dashboard.

The problem i'm getting is if i try to filter the data out with a function the data from the mqtt in does not come through anymore.

[image: This is what i used to work with and this worked.]

[image: I want this switch to disable the motion sensor]

It does not really matter how it is disabled but i need to be able to do it from the UI.
Can anyone help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The top example is the correct approach, you will need to use a switch node after the MQTT-in node to filter it's output, but have it trigger on a context variable set by the UI toggle node

Comment: @hardillb thank you for the info I got it working with the context variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using a context variable on the UI switch node and then using a switch that filters on the context variable.
[working flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYZMW.png)